# tomcat won't start after changing default port

Tags: tomcat

I am using tomcat7 and I changed it's deafult port from 8080 to 80.
After that when I tried to restart the server it won't start.
It is failing to start.

I changed the port in /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml
While changing it I modified the file permissions for server.xml as it was earlier readonly.
I tried to look at catalina logs in /var/log/tomacat7/catalina.xx.xx.xxxx
and found out that I changed server.xml and now tomcat cannot find the context from server.xml

The logs states that "SEVERE: Cannot load server context from server.xml"
Apologies that I cannot provide actual logs at the moment.
I'm really baffled that I just changed the port and nothing else.
Even reverting the change won't start tomcat.

I'd be really thankful for any help over this issue.

I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit server on amazon ec2 instance.
I tried with checking for processes those might be running on port 80 or 8080 and kill them but that too didn't help.

Comment: Do you start it as root? Ports below 1024 can only be bound by administrators/root users.

Comment: yes I started it as a root.

Comment: It can be caused by a changed permission on server.xml. Maybe tomcat have no more access to file. You don't need to change permission on file. Use sudo :)

Comment: Thnks for ur reply, I changed the permissions back to readonly, but that too didn't helped.
Changed it useing chmod 400 server.xml

Comment: Have you made sure that your server.xml is still valid XML? Could be a typo? You could also try downloading a new copy of tomcat and replacing the server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port back to 8080 and try to run. If it works perfectly then the port you selected is maybe not available because it fall under root port. Why dont try to use other ports example like 8081,8085, 80XX....?